# How to Output Values From Another File in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have two folders with a few files in each folder

- services

  - dns.tf
- app

  - outputs.tf

In the dns.tf I have the following:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "pgsql_master_record" {
  count   = var.pgsql_enabled ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = data.cloudflare_zone.this.id
  name    = "${var.name}.pg.${var.jurisdiction}"
  value   = module.db[0].primary.ip_address.0.ip_address
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 3600
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "redis_master_record" {
  count   = var.redis_enabled ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = data.cloudflare_zone.this.id
  name    = "${var.name}.redis.${var.jurisdiction}"
  value   = module.redis[0].host
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 3600
}
```

And in my app outputs.tf I'd like to add outputs for the above resources

```
output "psql_master_record" {
  value = cloudflare_record.pgsql_master_record[*].hostname
}

output "redis_master_record" {
  value = cloudflare_record.redis_master_record[*].hostname
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

*A managed resource "cloudflare_record" "redis_master_record" has not been declared in the root module.*

Comment: Your high-level objective here is unclear, but best guess is that you need to organize both into modules and declare both from a root module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it.
Your `dns.tf` and `outputs.tf` should be in the same folder

Or as example, you can use data block with remote state

In Terraform, you can output values from a configuration using the output block. These outputs can then be referenced within the same configuration using interpolation syntax, or from another configuration using the terraform_remote_state data source.

Here's an example of how you might use the output block to output the value of an EC2 instance's ID:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...
}

output "instance_id" {
  value = aws_instance.example.id
}
```

You can then reference the output value within the same configuration using "output.instance_id.value".

To use the output value from another configuration, you'll first need to create a data source for the remote state using the terraform_remote_state data source. Here's an example of how you might do that:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "example" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "my-tf-state-bucket"
    key    = "path/to/state/file"
    region = "us-west-2"
  }
}
```

Then, you can reference the output value from the remote configuration using "data.terraform_remote_state.example.output.instance_id.value".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to run terraform per directory. In the same directory you can have multiple terraform files and use variables from file A in file B. You are currently splitting it in 2 directories, that is only possible with a module approach. And this does not work out-of-the-box.

This [thread](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/call-a-terraform-variable-from-a-different-directory/25044) should clarify it.